# How to get input back from the form in a Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

How would I go about getting input back from the web page using a java servlet? I am doing this in Netbeans to try and retrieve input from this form I created. All the html tags are written in the java servlet is this the right way to do it?

```
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
          out.println("<title>Servlet Assignment1</title>");
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
          out.println("<form method='POST'>");
           out.println("<br>Enter your login information<br>");
           out.println("<br>User ID: ");
           out.println("<input type='text' name='userid'>");
           out.println("<br>Password: ");
           out.println("<input type='text' name='password'><br>");
           out.println("<input type='submit' name='submit'>");
          out.println("</form>");
         out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");


        String n1=request.getParameter("userid");

        out.println(n1);
```

This returns null. Do I have to have a button click to do this step?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<form action>`

write the servlet's URL pattern inside form action:

```
<form action="somesrvlet">

</form>
```

or use `<form target>`

```
<form target=_self>

    </form>
```

This should work!

**Suggestion:** 
Your code will show `null` the first time you run it but after submitting the form the value will be displayed!

To avoid that you may modify your code as:

```
String n1=request.getParameter("userid");
if(n1 != null)
        out.println(n1);
```